# tabpages related

Tags: c#, winforms

when I try to switch between the tabs on Windows Form,it's not working one method.
  the first method is clearing comboBoxes and the second method is adding to the inside of combobox those datas from SQL 
  the moral of the story,I'm adding a new data and then I can't see it within another comboboxes

```
if (tabAna.SelectedTab == tabFormGuncelle)
        {
            CombolariTemizle();
            BaglantiHazirla();
        }

if (tabAna.SelectedTab == tabFormOnayla)
       {
           CombolariTemizle();
           BaglantiHazirla();
       }
```

Comment: Better show where this code fits in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can only see that both codepaths are identical, i.e. both if-bodies are exactly the same. Possibly that's the reason?